# Remove specific string with quoted substring at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gsub

I want to remove all occurrences of **data-content="..."** from my string.

The characters between the double quotes will change and are dynamic.

I have tried something like

```rb
gsub(/data-content=[^'"]+K(.).*?\1/,'')
```

However, this does not match `data-content="..."` strings, how can I fix my regex?

Comment: Is data-content part of a string? or it's just `'data-content="abc123"'`

Comment: Which characters should be removed? Those within the quotes? Or should the chars inside the quotes be retained and only the data-content=""-wrapper should be removed?

Comment: The data-content is also part of the string, I want to remove.

Comment: Does `text.gsub(/\s*data-content="[^"]*"/, '')` work as expected? See https://ideone.com/2xtlSH

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew that worked perfectly, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```rb
text.gsub(/\s*data-content="[^"]*"/, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P3Rsiu/1) and the [Ruby demo online](https://ideone.com/2xtlSH):

```rb
text = 'text data-content="abc123" string'
puts text.gsub(/\s*data-content="[^"]*"/, '')
## => text string
```

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `data-content="` - a fixed string
- `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than double quotes
- `"` - a `"` char.